# How to pass totality check when traversing recursive data structure with `map`

Tags: idris

For example, I have the following code:

```
data Tree = Branches (List Tree) | Node Int

sumTree : Tree -> Int
sumTree (Branches xs) = sum (map sumTree xs)
sumTree (Node x) = x
```

If I want it pass the totality check, I have to expand map manually:

```
data Tree = Branches (List Tree) | Node Int

sumTree : Tree -> Int
sumTree (Branches xs) = sum' xs where
  sum' [] = 0
  sum' (x::xs) = sumTree x + sum' xs
sumTree (Node x) = x
```

Which makes a lot of power with functional programming not available if I want to avoid assert_total everywhere. Is there any way to workaround this issue?

Comment: I would suggest to open an issue about totality checker on Idris's GitHub. Analogous Coq code (with `map`) is accepted as total.

Comment: @AntonTrunov Thank you for pointing out GitHub issues, I have reported though it may be not very easy to fix.